# 2D array in Class isn't being defined

Tags: python, arrays, class, undefined, nameerror

Here I basically what I am doing is, in the class Circle I am trying to make an array with the points on the perimeter that are 10 degrees apart.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, rad, originX, originY):
        self.rad = rad
        self.woriginX = originX
        self.woriginY = originY
        self.tenDegreePts= [[]]

        for theta in range(0, 360, 10):
            b = round((np.cos(theta)))*rad
            a = round((np.sin(theta)))*rad
            tenDegreePts[0].append(originX+b)
            tenDegreePts[1].append(originY+a)
```

The problem is that when I type this into another line:

```
circle1 = Circle(75,300,300)
```

It gives me an error saying: `NameError: name 'tenDegreePts' is not defined`

Comment: Even if you fix this, your code still won't work, because `tenDegreePts` only contains one element (a list) so `tenDegreePts[1]` will cause an IndexError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing the `name 'tenDegreePts' is not defined`**

You should access the variable using `self`, like this:

```py
self.tenDegreePts[0].append(originX+b)
```

Nowhere you defined a variable named `tenDegreePts`, you just defined the variable `self.tenDegreePts`.

If it works for `rad`, that's because `rad` is defined as a method parameter but `tenDegreePts` isn't.

**Fixing other problems to come**

Fixing the previous issue won't be enough to make your program work, as noted in the comments.

```py
self.tenDegreePts[0].append(originX+b)
```

will work because `self.tenDegreePts[0]` is defined. Its value is initially `[]` as you wrote: `self.tenDegreePts= [[]]`.

But

```py
self.tenDegreePts[1].append(originX+b)
```

will crash with an index out of range error because there is no such second element in your list. `self.tenDegreePts[1]` indeed tries to access the second element in the `self.tenDegreePts` list. You should maybe initialize it like this instead:

```py
self.tenDegreePts = [[], []] #two items to start with (both empty lists)
```

Comment: You should also address `tenDegreePts` only having one element.item.